# Firewalld - blocking robots and penetration tests on web application (80 / 443)

Tags: centos, networking, security, firewall, firewalld

It looks like a penetration test is running against a web-application deployed on my centOS7 server. How can I block incoming requests on port 80 and 443, coming from the source IP address 11.21.32.44

I would block it using the OS firewall, centOS7 use firewalld

Reading from [fedora documentation](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/FirewalldRichLanguage#Handle_rich_rules_with_the_command_line_client) the rule should be something similar to this:

```
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule="
  rule family='ipv4'
  source address='11.21.32.44'
  port protocol='tcp' port='443' reject"
```

Ok, now thinking better, I would like to find a way to automatically block specific IP address after N requests with 404 httpd response

Comment: I'm not sure if firewalld is enough. Look at snort. It's IDS/IPS software for Linux

Comment: mod_security is probably worth a look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ModSecurity, https://modsecurity.org/, https://www.feistyduck.com/books/modsecurity-handbook/

Answer (score 0):

If it's some bot it should be safe to reject all its connection attempts (regardless of the destination port).

For that it's sufficient to add it's IP-address or range to the firewalld block zone:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=block --add-source=203.0.113.208/29
```

You might determine the range by querying one logged address via `whois $someip` and using `ipcalc -d` or some database of well-known unwanted bots.

Of course, adding single addresses is also possible.

You may want to add `--permanent` to persist those blockings.

---

Note that firewalld just rejects new connections, not established ones, such that an established connection to your web-server might still fill your logs.

To also get rid of those you can kill them with `ss`:

```
ss -K dst 203.0.113.208
```

(yes, you have to use `dst` for the source address of the bot)

---

Automating this is tricky because there are several risks involved:

- you increase your attack surface (this isn't a theoretical risk, you may want to search for past [fail2ban CVEs](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-5567/Fail2ban.html) and similar)
- too many false-positives, i.e. your automatic system might over-block, i.e. blocking legitimate visitors/customers or even yourself
- ...

Comment: If really want to block address+port tuples you can create an IPSet for that and use that (also using firewall-cmd).